# How to avoid redundancy here?

Tags: verbs, vocabulary, syntactic-analysis

> When I finally caught him, he **was** bleeding and **was** too weak to swim.

The sentence seems awkward to me and I don't know how to rephrase it. I think "was" is kinda redundant but just omitting it doesn't help the sentence much. Any suggestions?

Comment: At least [half-a-dozen writers in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bleeding+and+too+weak+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) don't share your misgivings. You're quite right that the second ***was*** is unnecessary (and wouldn't normally be included), but once that's taken care of, what's your problem?

Comment: So add a modifier instead: "When I finally caught him, he was bleeding and **far** too weak to swim."

Comment: It doesn't look awkward to me. It looks normal. (without the extra 'was')

Comment: Yeah, this one seems quite good. I was trying to find a way to cut the last part of the sentence and stick it some where else. I didn't know adding a modifier might change it so much.

Comment: Why use _when_ at all? You don't refer to time, only to the event. _I finally caught him, bleeding and too weak to swim._

Comment: @JohnLawler - I think that takes it too far. That could mean that you were in a bad state instead of him.

Comment: Only if you pronounce it wrong.